# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint -when joining two differnet data types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables.

Table1.Column1  where column 1 is a BIGInt. 
On
Table2.Column2 where column 2 is Nvarchar.

Here is what I am running

```
Select HspId, CMSid, Cast(CMSId as nvarchar)
From Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old
inner Join HSP on HSP.CMSid = Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old.POS
```

I am getting the following Error: Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Even if I do not cast anything I get the same error.

Comment: That's perfect. Both column `DataType` should be same. You may require casting or something else.

Comment: Since i had the same problem but except inner join i used UNION, convert both id's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the join.

```
Select HspId, CMSid, Cast(CMSId as nvarchar)
From Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old
inner Join HSP on CAST(HSP.CMSid as nvarchar) = Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old.POS
```

Answer (score 0):

First, always use a length with `varchar` in SQL Server.

Second, converting in the `select` has no effect on the `on`, so you need to convert twice.

Perhaps you intend:

```
Select HspId, CMSid, Cast(CMSId as nvarchar(255))
From Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old inner Join
     HSP
     on Cast(HSP.CMSId as nvarchar(255)) = Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old.POS;
```

Usually, I would recommend that you use `try_convert()`.  Conversion to strings is pretty safe, though, so you can confident that it will work.

Comment: why 255? min value of bigint is 19 digits and a minus sign, so 20 should be long enough....

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . I just use `255` as a reasonable length for most strings.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server tries to implicitly convert the `nvarchar` to `bigint`.
You need to convert the `bigint` to `nvarchar` explicitly to avoid exceptions if your `nvarchar` column contains values that can't be converted to `bigint`:

```
Select HspId, CMSid, Cast(CMSId as nvarchar(20))
From Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old
inner Join HSP on Cast(HSP.CMSid as nvarchar(20)) = Q2IMSSiteHistory2015old.POS
```

Also, When you cast to any string value (char, varchar, nchar or nvarchar) you should always specify the max length of the string. SQL Server has a [default length of 30](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#arguments), that should be enough in this case, but as best practice always specify length.